# PyTorch torchvision dataset download speed is very slow

Tags: python, download, pytorch, torchvision

I have the following code block in a colab notebook that downloads the EMNIST dataset from torchvision. Sometimes I randomly get an error saying

```
connectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.itl.nist.gov', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /iaui/vip/cs_links/EMNIST/gzip.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f701d0936d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

So I have made a code block with a function that calls itself if the attempt to download fails (see bottom of post). Sometimes the download actually starts working, but it's extremely slow. See below screenshot for progress bar

[image]
Over two hours to download <1GB of data from the URL in the screenshot. Downloading the dataset directly to my machine took about 60 seconds, so it's not a problem with the server that's serving the data. It seems to be a problem with either colab's internet connection with the server or the way that PyTorch is handling the data download.I don't really know what to do to solve this issue. I tried reconnecting runtime many times but the same issue happened.

Data Download Code:

```
from torchvision import transforms, datasets

train_data = None
test_data = None
def load_data():
  global train_data, test_data
  try:
    train_data = datasets.EMNIST("./data", split="balanced", train=True, download=True,
                                transform=transforms.Compose([
                                                              transforms.ToTensor()
                                ]))

    test_data = datasets.EMNIST("./data", split="balanced", train=False, download=True,
                                transform=transforms.Compose([
                                                              transforms.ToTensor()
                                ]))
  except:
    load_data()

load_data()
print(train_data)
print(test_data)
```

Comment: If you have downloaded the dataset on your machine, try uploading/saving that on cloud and then donwload from cloud. It is 10 times faster. I did the similar task using GCS, could be one another way

Comment: That solves my problem - thanks. But my question is why is this happening and is there any way to fix it so that it will work with colab?

Comment: What i concluded and not 100% sure, it depends on server too. The number of calls that it can handle. Sometimes, too many clients calling the same open server returns http connection break. It happens with me, too often with coco dataset as well

Comment: @ShreyJoshi, i think that the lag comes from you having to call the load_data function to often, and in your machine it works well because there are no connection errors with the server while in colab there are.

Comment: I get the error without the load_data function so wrapping the code in that function that calls itself if there is an error retries the connection if it fails.